# How do I capitalize the first letter of each text input in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

This is may code so far. I would like the FIRST_Name and LAST_Name fields to capitalize the first letter and have all other letters small:

Also, I am unfamiliar with javaScript so I am not exactly sure what I am doing.

**latest edit. What is wrong with this code?**

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function CheckForm()

formObj.FIRST_Name.value = titleCase(formObj.FIRST_Name.value);
formObj.LAST_Name.value = titleCase(formObj.LAST_Name.value);

function titleCase(str) {
    var words = str.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
        words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
    return words.join(" ");
}


{
  var formObj = document.getElementById("Data");
  var firstname = formObj.FIRST_Name.value;
  var lastname = formObj.LAST_Name.value;


    if(notEmpty(formObj.FIRST_Name, "Please enter your first name")){       
    if(notEmpty(formObj.LAST_Name,"Please enter your last name")){  
    if(titleCase(formObj.FIRST_Name)            

    return true;}}

    return false;
    }

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
    if(elem.value.length == 0){
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div style="background: #CCCC99">
<HR><FORM id="Data" onsubmit="return CheckForm()" action="post to server" method=post>
<P>First Name: <input type=text name=FIRST_Name maxlength=15 size=15>
   Last Name:  <input type=text name=LAST_Name maxlength=15 size=15></P>
<input type=submit value="Submit Products Registration Form" style="width: 220px"><input type=reset value="Reset">
</form>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It's simpler to use this regular expression: `/\b\w/g` then just replace the match (a single character) with the upper-case version. `\b` means "word boundary". (It will even work across hyphens, which may or may not be desirable :-)

Comment: @pst - Allowing for white-space at the beginning is a good idea and `\b` should do that, but the original code also changes the rest of the text to lowercase.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Check whether the input is in the correct format (and alert)? Correct it when submitting (then serverside would be OK as well)? Correct live while typing (very annoying)?

Comment: The `titleCase()` function added when you edited the question will not work (it has an error: `pieces` is not defined - should be `words`).

Comment: Just fixed that in an edit. Sorry...

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
String.prototype.toCap = function()
{ 
   return this.toLowerCase().replace(/^.|\s\S/g, function(str) { 
       return str.toUpperCase(); 
   });
}        

var firstname = "gob".toCap();
var lastname = "bluth".toCap();

alert(firstname + ' ' + lastname);
```

Comment: You can do easier with \b - see my answer

Answer (score 4):

For those of us who are scared of regular expressions (lol):

```
function titleCase(str)
{
    var words = str.split(" ");
    for ( var i = 0; i < words.length; i++ )
    {
        var j = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        words[i] = j + words[i].substr(1);
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: @dykeag: Looks good, only the array to join is still named `words`...

Comment: @TheCount What are you doing with the string after your capitalize it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
function toTitleCase(str){
    var words = str.match(/\w*/g);
    for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
        words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
    return words.join(' ');
}
toTitleCase('my name');
```

Comment: I think the question is how to integrate said `toTitleCase` function .. e.g. on blur or before submit or .. ?

Comment: Match for whitespaces? I'm sure you meant `split`

Comment: @Bergi whitespaces? No, I'm matching \w (letters and numbers)

Comment: Uh, I'm tired :-| OK, you really want to use match - but then you need to catch null in the case it does *not* match, for example on empty strings or unicode characters.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. In this case, we have to use `/\w*/g` instead of `/\w+/g` . Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

> *"don't know how to put it into my code"*

Copy the `titleCase()` (or `toTitleCase()` or whatever you are calling it now) function into your script block, and then add the following code just before the `if` statements in your `CheckForm()` function:

```
formObj.FIRST_Name.value = titleCase(formObj.FIRST_Name.value);
formObj.LAST_Name.value = titleCase(formObj.LAST_Name.value);
```

That way at the point where the form is submitted the fields will be changed using your `toTitleCase()` function. (If you add the code before the `if` statements the fields will be changed regardless of whether the `notEmpty()` validations pass, which seems reasonable to me.)

(Incidentally, the `firstname` and `lastname` variable declarations can be deleted from the `CheckForm()` function because you don't ever use those variables.)

Comment: Well as I commented above, the `titleCase()` function you edited into your question has an error in it (which has since been fixed in dykeag's answer). And as I said in my answer, the change to the values would only happen on submit - but to me that seems OK and you didn't specify otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

To uppercase a single string see [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026069/1048572).

If you want to to this on every word in the string, you will want to split the string into words, apply the `ucFirst` function on each of them and join them back together:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var words = str.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
        words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
    return words.join(" ");
}
```

Or you can apply a regex on them, to match every first letter and replace them:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\b\S/g, function(c){
        return c.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

---

At your latest edit: You've got an syntax error in the  third if-condition, it lacks a closing bracket. Also, you've inserted the `titleCase` code before the function body.

```
/* the titleCase function from above here */

function CheckForm() {
    var formObj = document.getElementById("Data");
    var firstname = formObj.FIRST_Name;
    var lastname = formObj.LAST_Name;

    firstname.value = titleCase(firstname.value);
    lastname.value = titleCase(lastname.value);

    return notEmpty(firstname, "Please enter your first name")
      && notEmpty(lastname, "Please enter your last name");
}

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
    if(elem.value.length == 0){
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My personal view on this: Don't try to correct the names with JavaScript at all. You do it when the form is committed, and the user will see effects of this action only if he left one input empty and encounters the error message.

You need to do this anyway serverside (never trust user input / POST data, javascript could be disabled), so if you aren't familiar with JavaScript (or don't like it or whatever), just omit this "feature".